# Using data from x3 combo boxes to textbox sum totals in excel userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on **excel user form** that I wish to add a time sheet that will **calculate total time** has taken that day and a sum total for the total hours over 5 days.

[image]

I have got the combo boxes to show the times. I wish to use using **dynamic named ranges** on a different worksheet.

But I am struggling to get this text box to sum or even showing.

Any help would be appreciatable.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, so that we can help you fix it...

Comment: Try using events, maybe some check after combobox_exit